# Dynamic input compilation

Tags: angularjs, recursion, angularjs-directive

I try to build inputs dynamically basing on object server returned.
I using angularJS directives.
Since the object is tree-like, I used recursion.

The problem is generated  don't bind to the model.

HTML:

```html
<div ng-app="dyno">
  <div ng-controller="fieldCompilation">
    <br><br><b> Directive Inputs 1 (param via attr):</b><br>

    <form action="" name="myForm1" novalidate>
      <div ng-repeat="(itbl, tbl) in from1">
        <div ng-repeat="(irec, rec) in tbl">
          <div ng-repeat="(iel, el) in rec">
            <build-fields1 list="el"></build-fields1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      Form validity: {{myForm1.$valid}}<br>
            Model: {{from1[1][1061][0].value}}
    </form>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
app = angular.module('dyno', []);

app.directive('buildFields1', ['$compile',
  function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        list: '=list'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        var e = scope.list;
        switch (e.tagName) {
          case 'input':
            element.append(e.label + ' <' + e.tagName + ' name="' + e.name + '" placeholder="' + e.attrs.toString() + '" type="text" ng-change="' + e.func + '(' + e.param + ')" ng-model="' + e.value + '" ' + e.attrs.toString() + '>');
            break;
                    case 'select':
          element.append(e.label + '<' + e.tagName + ' name="'+e.name+'" ng-change="'+e.func+'(-2)" ng-model="'+e.name+'" ng-options="x.id as x.name for x in '+e.items.toString()+'">');
                    break;
          case 'ref':
            element.append('<div ng-repeat="(itbl, tbl) in $parent.' + e.value + '"><div ng-repeat="(irec, rec) in tbl"><div ng-repeat="(iel, el) in rec"><build-fields1 list="el"></build-fields1></div></div></div>');
            break;
        }

        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      }
    };
  }
]);
app.controller('fieldCompilation', function($scope) {
  var i;
  // FORM2
  // FORM1
  $scope.from1 = [{}];
  $scope.from1[1] = {};
  $scope.from1[1][1061] = {};
  i = 0;
  $scope.from1[1][1061][i++] = {
    tagName: 'input',
    name: 'tid',
    label: 'TID:',
    attrs: ["required pattern='[0-9]{8}'"],
    func: 'show',
    param: '20',
    value: '20000000',
  };
  $scope.from1[1][1061][i++] = {
    tagName: 'input',
    name: 'mid',
    label: 'MID:',
    attrs: ["required pattern='[0-9]{15}'"],
    func: 'show',
    param: '20',
    value: '123456789012345',
  };
  $scope.from1[1][1061][i++] = {
    tagName: 'select',
    name: 'sel',
    label: 'Class:',
    attrs: [],
    items: "[{id:'1',name:'A'},{id:'2',name:'B'},{id:'3',name:'C'}]",
    func: 'show',
  };
  $scope.from1[1][1061][i++] = {
    tagName: 'ref',
    name: 'ref',
    label: 'Ref:',
    attrs: ["required pattern='[0-9]{8}'"],
    func: 'show',
    param: '1', // of function
    value: 'from2',
  };

  $scope.from2 = [{}];
  $scope.from2[2] = {};
  $scope.from2[2][10] = {};
  i = 0;
  $scope.from2[2][10][i++] = {
    tagName: 'input',
    name: 'a',
    label: 'A:',
    attrs: ["required pattern='[0-9]{8}'"],
    func: 'show',
    param: '20',
    value: '10000001',
  };
  $scope.from2[2][10][i++] = {
    tagName: 'input',
    name: 'b',
    label: 'B:',
    attrs: ["required pattern='[0-9]{15}'"],
    func: 'show',
    param: '20',
    value: '882277441115599',
  };
  $scope.from2[2][10][i++] = {
    tagName: 'select',
    name: 'c',
    label: 'C:',
    attrs: [],
    items: "[{id:'1',name:'a'},{id:'2',name:'b'},{id:'3',name:'c'}]",
    func: 'show',
  };


});
```

Expected result is: when I type something in  (f.e. TID) it's model should change accordantly.
Now I get a fixed value in  which can't be changed at all.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vovaw/opm74unf/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line

```
element.append(e.label + ' <' + e.tagName + ' name="' + e.name 
   + '" placeholder="' + e.attrs.toString() + '" type="text" ng-change="'
   + e.func + '(' + e.param + ')" ng-model="' + e.value + '" '
   + e.attrs.toString() + '>');
```

to

```
element.append(e.label + ' <' + e.tagName + ' name="' + e.name
   + '" placeholder="' + e.attrs.toString() + '" type="text" ng-change="'
   + e.func + '(' + e.param + ')" ng-model="list.value" '
   + e.attrs.toString() + '>');
```

If you debug your code and look at the actual value you're doing this once it's compiled:

```
<input name="tid" placeholder="required pattern='[0-9]{8}'" type="text"
       ng-change="show(20)" ng-model="20000000" required=""
       pattern="[0-9]{8}"
       class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-valid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-touched">
```

Notes that the `ng-model="2000000"` which is why you can never change it.  Because you're compiling it, you want the value `ng-model="list.value"` which is on the scope as `$scope.list.value` and therefore acceptable for ng-model.